# Search term grid: add date column with date-time picker

Tags: magento2, grid, magento2.4.2

In Magento 2.4, we want to display date column in grid as a filterable option with date-time picker. Can anybody please suggest a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code on this file :

`MagentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

```
<column name="date">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```